# CSS menu, display subnav on hover

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I made a custom mini navigation on a site I am working on, I need the subnav to display on hover just as I have it display on the category or page it is currently on but have not been able to select that properly.

It is the small navigation on the right with the radio/tv/contests/blog icons
Link: http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=radio

I thought this would work, but it doesn't

```
ul#mininav li#mntv a:hover ul#minisubnav li#subtv {
    display:inline !important;
}
```

Here is the code so far:

```
<ul id="mininav">
    <li id="mnradio"><a href="http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=radio">radio</a></li>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subradio">RADIO</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="mntv"><a href="http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=gctv">tv</a></li>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subtv">TV</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="mnblog"><a href="http://getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?cat=2">blog</a></li>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subblog">BLOG</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="mncontests"><a href="http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=contests">contests</a></li>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subcontests">CONTESTS</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="mnarchives"><a href="http://getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?page_id=108">archives</a></li>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subarchive">ARCHIVES</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="mnabout"><a href="http://getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?page_id=119">about</a></li>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subabout">ABOUT</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#mininav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px !important;
}

ul#mininav li a {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent url(images/mininav/mininav.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9009px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

ul#mininav li#mnradio a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnradio a:hover {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: 0px -31px;
}

.post-type-archive-radio ul#minisubnav li#subradio {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -40px;
}

.single.single-radio ul#minisubnav li#subradio {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -40px;
}

ul#mininav li#mntv a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -33px 0px;
}

ul#mininav li#mntv a:hover {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -33px -31px;
}

ul#mininav li#mntv a:hover ul#minisubnav li#subtv {
    display: inline !important;
}

.post-type-archive-gctv ul#minisubnav li#subtv {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -27px;
}

.single.single-gctv ul#minisubnav li#subtv {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -27px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnblog a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -66px 0px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnblog a:hover {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -66px -31px;
}

.category-blog.category-2 ul#mininav li#mnblog a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -66px -31px;
}

.category-blog.category-2 ul#minisubnav li#subblog {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -38px;
}

.single.single-post ul#minisubnav li#subblog {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -38px;
}

.single.single-post.category-2 ul#minisubnav li#subblog {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -38px;
}

ul#mininav li#mncontests a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -99px 0px;
}

ul#mininav li#mncontests a:hover {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -99px -31px;
}

.post-type-archive-contests ul#mininav li#mncontests a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -99px -31px;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subcontests {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -75px;
    left: 90px;
}

.post-type-archive-contests ul#minisubnav li#subcontests {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -53px;
}

.single.single-contests ul#minisubnav li#subcontests {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -53px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnarchives a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -132px 0px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnarchives a:hover {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -132px -31px;
}

.page.page-id-108 ul#mininav li#mnarchives a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -132px -31px !important;
}

.page.page-id-108 ul#minisubnav li#subarchive {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -53px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnabout a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -165px 0px;
}

ul#mininav li#mnabout a:hover {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -165px -31px;
}

.page.page-id-119 ul#mininav li#mnabout a {
    width: 30px;
    background-position: -165px -31px;
}

.page.page-id-119 ul#minisubnav li#subabout {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -42px;
}

.page-child.parent-pageid-119 ul#minisubnav li#subabout {
    display: inline;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -42px;
}

ul#minisubnav {
    width: 235px;
}

ul#minisubnav li {
    color: #a7a9ac;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subradio {
    display: none;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subtv {
    display: none;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subblog {
    display: none;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subcontests {
    display: none;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subarchive {
    display: none;
}

ul#minisubnav li#subabout {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subnav `ul`s need to be children of your top level `li`s, like so:

```
<li id="mnradio"><a href="http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=radio">radio</a>
    <ul id="minisubnav">
        <li id="subradio">RADIO</li>
    </ul>
</li><!-- #mnradio -->
```

Then in the CSS you'll need to select your `li` for the `:hover` target rather than the anchor in order to show the child subnav `li`. The subnav `ul` is not a child of the anchor tag which is why you'll need to use the actual parent tag, the `li`, as the hover target:

```
li#mnradio:hover li#subradio {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

I would actually recommend, however, that you hide the whole subnav `ul` instead of the just the `li`, then show the `ul` with the hover target:

```
ul#minisubnav {
    display: none;
}
li#mnradio:hover ul#minisubnav {
    display: block;
}
```

Also I recommend changing all your subnav `id`s to `class`es. Technically speaking there is only supposed to be one `id` per page. If you're reusing that `id`, change it to be a class instead. See the spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html.

Comment: thanks for this, helped a lot. I totally goofed on the </li>.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your markup is wrong. You are embedding the inner 'ul' outside the li.

Try changing

```
<ul id="mininav">
<li id="mnradio"><a href="http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=radio">radio</a></li>
<ul id="minisubnav">
.
.
.
</ul
```

>

to

```
<ul id="mininav">
<li id="mnradio"><a href="http://www.getconnectedmedia.com/wp/?post_type=radio">radio</a>
<ul id="minisubnav">
</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

Elements do have syntax. Please don't violate them. The only element that can be the direct child of a ul is the 'li'